# How can I integrate docusign with vuejs app

Tags: node.js, vue.js, widget, docusignapi

I have a vue app where I have a consent widget which displays the consent content and asks the user to read and sign to continue with the study that follows.
I want to integrate docusign for the signing part. How can I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your server is Node.JS so I would try to look at our NodeJS SDK and Code Examples:

https://github.com/docusign/docusign-node-client

https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant

Also, if you just need consent, I would consider using Click instead of the eSignature API:

https://developers.docusign.com/click-api

Comment: is there an example of how to use the nodeJS SDK? @